# open google picker in chrome extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-picker

I have been trying to open google picker from a chrome extension. I want to select a file from google drive and get the info about the file. I use manifest v3 for my extension. I am tried to implement this using an Iframe, but sandboxed iframe throws Blocked script execution in   because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set. My iframe already has 'allow-same-origin' and adding 'allow-script' it exits the sandbox and throws `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws://localhost:undefined/' is invalid.`

Script it is blocking is 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'

this is how I am calling iframe in my extension
`<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin" className="picker-html" src={chrome.runtime.getURL("picker.html")}></iframe>`

this is contents in my picker.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sandboxed Content</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sandboxed Content</h1>
    <p>I am the sandboxed iframe.</p>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "example",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": { "default_title": "click me" },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "storage",
      "identity"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "js": ["content.tsx"],
        "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"]
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "service-worker.ts",
      "type": "module"
    }
}
```

I am expecting to click a button and open google picker and get the file info back to extension.

Comment: Instead of using the attribute declare [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/) in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried that. I am using crxjs https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/ to build this extension and I think it does not work great with sandbox page. Is there any other way I can achieve this?